# Ramda doesn't work within Mongoose query callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ramda.js

I'm writing REST API using NodeJS, Express, Mongoose, Ramda. I need to prepare response for client using Ramda's utilities but I am encountering some issues:

```
const R = require('ramda');

router.put('/:id/update', (req, res) => {
  User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { '_id': req.params.id },
    { $set: { a: 'a' }},
    {},
    (err, newUser) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(responseCodes.updateUserError());
      } else {
        const exemplaryObj = { a: 'a', email: 'bbb' };
        console.log(
          newUser, // { email: 'aaa', password: 'bbb' }
          R.omit(['email', 'password'], newUser), // { email: 'aaa', password: 'bbb' }
          R.omit(['email', 'password'], exemplaryObj) // { a: 'a' }
        )
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Why Ramda's `omit` (or other methods like `merge`) doesn't work as expected with objects returned by Mongoose query callbacks?

Comment: If you console.log(newUser), you get this { 'email: 'aaa', 'password: 'bbb' }?

Comment: Yup, together with other properties but including `email` and `password`. They are not nested inside some other property, the structure is the same as in the simplified example that I provided

Comment: You are using Ramda first time with (), and second time without. Could be that?

Comment: No, sorry, it's my typo :) let me fix that

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Yes, please check out Steve's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the **toObject** method to convert the returned document to a plain JavaScript object:

```
 R.omit(['email', 'password'], newUser.toObject())
```

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject

You could alternatively add **lean** to the query chain to tell Mongoose to return just the plain JavaScript object:

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean